# When softassert fails, the failure screenshot attached in the extent report is not the expected screenshot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Is there a way we can add failure screenshot in the extent report when any test step fails due to soft assert ?

Right now it is attaching the screenshot of the last screen, where the test ends

Note: Screenshot attachment for hard assert works fine

Comment: Any TestNG, Extent Report experts ??

Comment: I think there is no solution to this, but still need comment from experts